# Smooth scrolling on windows Phone 7 mobile site

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, css, mobile-website

I am creating a mobile webapp for windows phone 7.5 devices and would like a box with `overflow:scroll` to scroll smoothly (not stop when you release the content on scrolling with your finger).

Now for iOS this exists: `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;`

Is there any similar thing for WP7? I tried `overflow-scrolling:touch;` and `-ms-overflow-scrolling:touch;` but those do not work.

Is there an online resource for WP7.5 web development?

Any javascript alternative?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the only way to do it is using a JavaScript Scrolling to replace the default auto scroll.

Take a look at [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll) or something similar